# How do I make a timer that gives the same time for every user even if they close the app

Tags: java, android

I need to do a count down timer for 24 hours but the timer needs to give equal time to all users and simultaneous.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO. 
 You should also read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Yes, you need to be much more specific on how your app will be working with multiple people.  Will one person set the count down timer?  How will they do that?  Are you going to develop a web API to manage the updates to all users?  By 'all users' do you mean every user that has ever downloaded the app?  Or can you group certain people together?

Comment: It's like a countdown to an event, I'll start the timer 24 hours before the event and users can check how much time remains @MichaelDougan

Answer (score 0):

Nobody here can really help you too much because the question is very vague and there isn't much for us to work off of, but I'll give answering it a shot and we'll see how that goes.

If I am correct, you're asking how you can make your program show every user the same timer. To do that you're going to need a server with the timer information. Each user's program should send a request for the timer information to the server whenever it needs the information and then your program does what it does with the information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even really need a timer for that.  You just need to post the exact date/time of the event on a web page.  In the app, on app start-up, it reads the date of the event from your web page, converts it to a Java Datetime object, then gets the current Datetime and does a date diff compare, to display how long until the event date/time.  If you wish, you set a timer in the app, and every second or minute you get the current time again and update the date diff display.